# CGO; C function has int pointer argument, how to pass correct type?

Tags: go, cgo

Currently I'm using Cgo to call C functions from Go. I'm trying to recreate the ['Read a Photo'](http://libccv.org/galaxy-guide/) example in Go.

One on the C functions, however, expects a `int*  len` argument (bonus question; is that the same as `int *len`?). As I read this, this is a pointer to an integer. The function in question is [`ccv_write`](http://libccv.org/lib/ccv-io/) of the libccv library. It's full signature is:

`int ccv_write(ccv_dense_matrix_t* mat, char* out, int* len, int type, void* conf)`

The relevant code snippet is as follows:

```
type Image struct {
    image *C.ccv_dense_matrix_t
}

func main() {
    image := new(Image)

    /* ... snip ... */

    dst := C.CString("black_and_white_painting.jpg")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(dst))
    x := 0 // <- perhaps var x int ?
    C.ccv_write(image.image, dst, (*C.int)(&x), C.CCV_IO_PNG_FILE, 0)
}
```

The above example generates the following compile time error: `cannot convert &x (type *int) to type *_Ctype_int`

Any thoughts on how to pass the correct argument?

Comment: Yes, whitespace in C is rarely significant, `int *len;` and `int* len;` are equivalent. There's reasons (in my opinion) to prefer the former, since the latter looks like it's promising something that isn't true (namely, what does `int* a, b;` mean?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue here is you have two different types. You have an `int` which is defined by your Go compiler and `C.int` which is defined by your C compiler. Depending on the compilers and architecture these may be the same size. However, it is very possible that `int` will be 64 bits in size and `C.int` would be 32 bits.

In order for the compiler to enforce the type safety, it requires you to do an explicit conversion or define the type at initialization.

In your example, you do: `x := 0`. This is the same as `x := int(0)`. The `int` is implied. Instead, you can do `x := C.int(0)`.

However, I think the "cleaner" method would be to do what jnml recommended: `var x C.int`. This does exactly the same thing but just looks nicer.

---

Later, you will most likely want to convert that `C.int` back to an `int`. This is easy to do with a conversion.

```
y := int(x)
```

This will convert `x` to an `int` and then copy that value into the newly initialized variable `y`.

---

Bonus Anwser: `int* len` is indeed the same as `int *len`

Answer (score 9):

This seems to work for me:

```
package main

/*

void foo(int *len) { *len = 1234; }

*/
import "C"

func main() {
        var x C.int
        C.foo(&x)
        println(x)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need an `unsafe.Pointer` cast.

```
C.ccv_write(image.image, dst, (*C.int)(unsafe.Pointer(&x)), C.CCV_IO_PNG_FILE, 0)
```

Comment: This is the only way to allow the conversion you are trying to achieve. From [the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer): `unsafe.Pointer` allows a program to defeat the type system and read and write arbitrary memory. It should be used with extreme care.

Comment: An alternative would be to define `x` as `var x C.int`. Then you can pass it as `&x`. This won't work if your `x` comes from outside of your package though.

Comment: Yes, unsafe.Pointer is indeed a great way to break the type system. But this case does not call for such extreme measures. This may not give him the intended results if sizeof(int) != sizeof(C.int).